# Editing multiple cells in a datatable in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, shinydashboard

I asked this question earlier - [Write editable shiny Datatable to .csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58593824/write-editable-shiny-datatable-to-csv-file/58594994#58594994)
Trying to edit cells in a shiny datatable and replace the original data with the edited data.

I was able to figure out how to edit a single cell in the datatable, however if multiple cells are edited only the last edit is saved.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)


users <- reactiveFileReader(
  intervalMillis = 1000,  
  NULL,
  filePath = 'appData/userTest.csv',
  readFunc = read.csv,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "demo")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(uiOutput('sidebar'))
body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("body"))

f1 <- fluidRow(
  box(
    dataTableOutput('userTable'),
    width = 6
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'admin function test', header, sidebar, body, skin='blue')

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$body <- renderUI({
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = 'admin', class = 'active', h2(f1)
      )
    )
  })

  output$sidebar <- renderUI({
    sidebarMenu(id = 'sidebarmenu',
                menuItem("admin", tabName = "admin", icon = icon("adjust")),
                actionButton("do", 'save', icon = icon('redo'))
    )
  })

  observeEvent(
    input$do,{
      write.csv(edited(),'appData/userTest.csv', row.names = FALSE)
    })

  output$userTable <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(users(),
                  editable = TRUE,
                  rownames = FALSE)
  })

  edited <- reactive({editData(users(), input$userTable_cell_edit, proxy = NULL, rownames = FALSE, resetPaging = FALSE)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Data:

```
   userName      start        end
1      John 06/08/2019 01/10/2019
2      Mary 01/01/2019 01/10/2019
3      Mike 23/10/2019 01/10/2019
4     Steve 25/07/2019 07/02/2015
5      Kate 01/01/2019 29/04/2019
```

I imagine this is because the `editData()` function records only a single edit at a time.
How can multiple cells be edited and saved in one go?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956418/how-to-use-an-editable-datatable-in-shiny-as-input-for-another-datatable/49956815#49956815)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See below, this will allow multiple changes and each one is tracked.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "demo")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = 'sidebarmenu',
              menuItem("admin", tabName = "admin", icon = icon("adjust")),
              downloadButton("downloadResults","Download Results")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = 'admin', class = 'active', 
        fluidRow(
          box(
            dataTableOutput('userTable'), width = 6
          )
        )
    )
  )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'admin function test', header, sidebar, body, skin='blue')

server <- function(input, output, session){

  dat <- data.frame(userName = c("John","Mary","Mike"), start = c("06/08/2019","01/01/2019","23/10/2019"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  output$userTable <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(isolate(dat),
                  editable = TRUE,
                  rownames = FALSE)
  })

  ###Tracking Changes###
  rvs <- reactiveValues(
    data = NA #dynamic data object
  )

  observe({
    rvs$data <- dat
  })

  proxy = dataTableProxy('userTable')
  observe({
    DT::replaceData(proxy, rvs$data, rownames = FALSE, resetPaging = FALSE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$userTable_cell_edit, {
    rvs$data <<- editData(rvs$data, input$userTable_cell_edit, rownames = FALSE)
  })

  # observeEvent(
  #   input$do,{
  #     write.csv(rvs$data,'userTest.csv', row.names = FALSE)
  #   })

  output$downloadResults <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){paste("userTest.csv.csv", sep = "")},
    content = function(file){write.csv(rvs$data, file, row.names = FALSE)}
  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you want multiple cells to be editable at the same time, add this line to your datatable:

```
editable = list(target = "all") #can be all, row, or column
```

Few tips when posting in the future:

1. Create a reproducible example, having it pull data/save data from a file on your computer can't be reproduced
2. Keep the code simple as possible to focus on your issue. Throwing `renderUI`'s for the body and sidebar just clutters your code.

Comment: Hey Kevin, it is an old post, but could you explain the basic concepts of your code that allows it to keep replacing the data with each edit? I particularly don't understand the use of the proxy (Also, why `proxy =` instead of `proxy <-`?)